# Centring heading relative to image in HTML-CSS

Tags: html, css

I have floated an image left using:

```
img {
    float:left;
}
```

and have also centred a heading using:

```
<h1 align="center">Text</h1>
```

The heading moves position as the image is inserted so its no longer centred, its pushed to the right. How can I centre the heading again? I have tried a lot of different CSS properties for the heading but cant seem to get it working. Thanks.

Comment: Make a fiddle with what you have and don't use align to center text :)

Comment: FYI, `align` is a long-deprecated HTML attribute. As you're already using CSS, you should include `h1 { text-align: center; }` in there instead.

Comment: James I just changed that, thanks.

Comment: Bojan, what do you mean by fiddle?

Comment: You can show us your example recreating it in http://jsfiddle.net/ or you can make a code snippet right here :)

Comment: @BojanPetkovski <html>
 
 <body>
  <style>
  img {
   float:left;
  }
  
  h1 {
   color:red;
   font-family:Trebuchet MS;
   font-size:250%;
   text-align:center;
   
  }
  </style>
 
  <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="Highdown logo">
  <h1>Sports day</h1>
  
  
  
  <!--
  <button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Entry forms</button>
  -->
 </body>
 
 
</html>

Comment: sorry its not formatted, not sure how to do it

Comment: make your css h1{clear:both; text-align:center;}. Believe this is what you are looking for!!

Comment: @Aru almost worked.. the heading centred which was good however it moved down on the page so it was not in line with the image!

Comment: if possible can you post a screenshot of what you are looking for???

Comment: @Aru http://gyazo.com/75ca26aff1daf417b33b7ca53cb6b641    thats what i want the design to look like. currently the page look like http://gyazo.com/21b20ec1d60a79e2473df4aa4430b830

Comment: seems you need to reset your "h1" padding and margin, I've posted an answer, hope that helps you!!

Comment: this is the code http://gyazo.com/9ba746922d32f6fffaa717e647ecadb3

Answer (score 0):

try fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/aqofdz8u/

```
<div>
    <img src="http://drublic.de/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/rotate-images.jpg" width="220" height="220" alt="A photo of me.">
    <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
img {
    float:left;
}

h1 { text-align: center; }
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img src="http://www.nnsheriff.org/img/placeholder/blogpost-placeholder-100x100.png" alt="">
     <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img {
    float:left;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left:10px;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

[Fiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/aqofdz8u/3/)

Answer (score 0):

To make h1 be centered regading the whole page you need to add position: absolute to the img and add img and h1 inside a div with position relative.

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
h1 {
  color: red;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  font-size: 250%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://blog.grio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/stackoverflow.png" alt="Highdown logo" />
  <h1>Sports day</h1> 
</div>
```

Comment: If this answer helped you out please accept the answer so the question can be closed :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
h1 {
  color: red;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  font-size: 250%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://blog.grio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/stackoverflow.png" alt="Highdown logo" />
  <h1>Sports day</h1> 
</div>
```